# RecyclerView re-animate views on scrolling

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I want animate view on click of it. I am animating that view using `AnimatorSet`
But when user scroll at that time state of animation is not maintain or not clearAnimation properly. It will animate other item's icon.
anyone has idea on it?

animation method:

```
public static void likeAnimation(Object object) {
        if (object == null) {
            return;
        }
        AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
        Object myView = object;
        set.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        set.playTogether(
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "rotation", 0, 360)
        );
        set.setDuration(500).start();
    }
```

RecyclerView code:

```
 @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
  holder.imageView_like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(final View v) {
                      likeAnimation(v);
}

}
```

Comment: Basically recycler view is reusing the views, that will take car by Layout manager. Animation comes to consecutive item when you are scrolling.
may you write the logic - stop the animation when you are started scrolling. you came to know whether recycler view is scrolling or not when you override `onScroll()` method. In this you stop the animation

Comment: @Navaspk Yes, every time recyclerView call `onCreateViewHolder` so I use `clearAnimation()` for this view and I applied `clearAnimation` also into `onViewDetachedFromWindow(ViewHolder holder)` but still it is animating and not maintain state or stop animation.  if possible then suggest code or else. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're just in time with this question, and I hope I'm not too late. An idea here is very simple. You have to keep in mind that your `RecyclerView` reuses every single `ViewHolder` which has ever been created.  Usually, it creates about 7~8 items, but it depends on screen size.

So, in your particular case if you want to animate an item upon click, you have to track the state of every item in your `RecyclerView`. Basically, you can have three states:

- `Enter` state or your very animation. When the user clicks on some item from the list, you start animating that item, and in the end of animation switch the state of the item to `Animated` state.
- `Animated` state. This is the state of an item that has been animated, and doesn't need this animation again, so when the user scrolls up/down you just need to set a view into the animated state. In your case, you can try the following code:

  ```
  private void animatedState(View view){
    //perform the same action but without animation
    view.setRotation(360);
  }
  ```
- `Default` state or normal state. That is `View` without rotation, just a normal state.
   For instance,

  ```
  private void defaultState(View view){
    view.setRotation(0);
  }
  ```

Also you may want to animate the items back upon click, if yes, you have to add one more state which is an `Exit` state, and then switch from that state to the `Default` state.

You can find the entire implementation of this idea by this [link](https://github.com/vpaliyX/MultiChoiceMode-RecyclerView).